# How to print specfic values in an array based on input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a program that once user input is received based on that, specific parts of the array are printed.

This is my code so far:

```
players=['Player 1','Player 2','Player 3','Player 4','Player 5','Player 6','Player 7','Player 8']

playerammount=int(input("The game is starting! How many players are joining? (2-8): "))
if playerammount < 2:  #Make sure the max-min amount of players are accepted
    cont=input("Too few players.\nPress enter to try again")
    start()
if playerammount > 2:
    cont=input("Too many players.\nPress enter to try again")
    start()
names=input("What is the name of player")
```

I would like it so based on how many players are selected those are the players asked for names and not those past the amount registered.

I was planning on using a multiple-variable input line to save space by asking for all the player's names at once. Using: Split().

Comment: Please add more clearity, what exactly the issue or the problem you're facing

Comment: I'm trying to see how many players are joining the game. For each player joined I want them to have a specific username. Based off of this I want to edit the array titled "players" to not include more than the amount of players added and to be able to use split() to be able to type the names all in one input.

Comment: Your title is clear but then you make the whole question ambiguous with the content. What are you actually tying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to save space, then just ask for the names rather than numbers. Something like:

`players = input("The game is starting! Who is playing? Separate using commas.")`

You could then wrap it in a while loop to ensure that it's the right number of players. E.g.

```
while True:
    players_str = input("The game is starting! Who is playing? Separate using commas. (2-8 players allowed)")
    players = [name.strip() for name in players_str.split(',')]
    
    if len(players) < 2:
        print ("Too few players. Try again.")
    elif len(players) > 8:   # Note: Your original code had 2 here, which is incorrect
        print ("Too many players. Try again.")
    else:
        break
start()
```

Comment: This is the correct approach (except that you haven't implemented *start()*). There is no need to ask for the number of players. Just input them (comma separated) then split and count